# Cannot run supervisor specifying custom user

Tags: php, laravel, docker, docker-compose, supervisord

I'm building a Laravel image which runs with the user `backend` that have the id `1000`. This user should allow me to prevent the following error:

> File could not be opened in append mode: failed to open stream: Permission denied

The problem's that when I run the supervisor I get this error:

> IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/log/supervisord.log'

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:8.1.10-fpm-buster

WORKDIR /var/www

RUN docker-php-ext-install bcmath pdo_mysql

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y git zip unzip netcat

# Supervisor
RUN apt-get install -y supervisor

# Composer
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

# Configurations
COPY docker/php/config/supervisor.conf /etc/supervisord.conf
COPY docker/php/config/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/app.ini

# Log file
RUN mkdir /var/log/php
RUN touch /var/log/php/errors.log && chmod 777 /var/log/php/errors.log

# Deploy
COPY /docker/php/scripts/start.sh /start.sh
RUN chmod +x /start.sh

# Add user for laravel application
RUN groupadd -g 1000 backend
RUN useradd -u 1000 -ms /bin/bash -g backend backend

# Copy existing application directory contents
COPY . /var/www

# Copy existing application directory permissions
COPY --chown=backend:backend . /var/www

USER backend

EXPOSE 9000

ENTRYPOINT /start.sh
```

This is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.9'

services:

  php:
    container_name: ${APP_NAME}_app
    #user: ${CURRENT_UID}
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/php/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www
    env_file: .env
```

And this is the entrypoint script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Run composer install
composer install

# Generate key and clear cache
php artisan key:generate
php artisan config:clear
php artisan config:cache

# Wait db connection
until nc -z ${DB_HOST} ${DB_PORT}; do sleep 1; echo "Wait database ..."; done

# Execute migrations
php artisan migrate --seed

/usr/bin/supervisord -c /etc/supervisord.conf
```

Last but not least, the supervisor.conf:

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true
loglevel = info
logfile=/var/log/supervisord.log
pidfile=/var/run/supervisord.pid

[group:laravel-worker]
priority=999
programs=laravel-app,laravel-schedule,laravel-notification,laravel-queue

[program:laravel-app]
priority=5
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
command=/usr/local/sbin/php-fpm -R
stderr_logfile=/var/log/php/php-error.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/php/php-access.log

[program:laravel-schedule]
numprocs=1
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/artisan schedule:run
stdout_logfile=/var/log/php/schedule.log

[program:laravel-notification]
numprocs=1
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/artisan notification:worker
stdout_logfile=/var/log/php/notification.log

[program:laravel-queue]
numprocs=5
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
stdout_logfile=/var/log/php/worker.log
command=php /var/www/artisan queue:work sqs --sleep=3 --tries=3
```

Is there any way to fix the permission issue?

Comment: did you ever try adding a line like this:  COPY --chown=backend:backend . /var/log

Comment: @ErkanÖzkök I added the line as you suggested but same error

Comment: It looks like you're trying to run five separate processes; can you run them in five separate containers, without supervisord, in all cases letting their logs go to the container stdout?  That would avoid this permission problem and help you scale the components independently if needed.

Comment: @DavidMaze could be a solution, does you have a GitHub repo that show how to correctly setup a Laravel app with PHP 8 and docker? Would be really useful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my supervisord.conf as an example.
I am always adding `user=root` row. And never got a permission error.

```
[program:laravel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/artisan queue:work --sleep=3 --tries=3
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=root
numprocs=1
redirect_stderr=true
```

Comment: Error: Can't drop privilege as nonroot user

Comment: @sfarzoso were you able to find a solution to this issue? I'm running into the exact same issue using laravel too. Added `user=root` as Erkan suggested but made not difference at all in my case

Answer (score 0):

this issue because using `USER backend` in Docker file, you need to configure supervisor for using same user in Docker file `user=backend`

Comment: Same issue......

Comment: are you delete docker image and rebuild again

Comment: I'm using docker compose